# Regex technique for lazy group capturing (concrete case)

Tags: regex, lazy-evaluation, pcre

Suppose that you match text line by line. And in some cases the line may contain variable sized extra symbols. The problem is that narrow patterns for these extra symbols are not known, forcing to use wide-capturing patterns. These patterns in turn interfere with the text after.

Example (PCRE flavour, flags: *g, x, m*):

```
(?<a1>[0-9]{4})
(?:[ ](?<a2>\([A-Z]\)))?
(?:[ ](?<extra>[A-Za-z]+(?:[ ]+[A-Za-z]+)+))?
(?<a3>[ ](?:foo[ ][0-9])|(?:bar[ ][a-z]{2,5}[0-9]))?
(?<a4>[ 0-9]+)
```

Matched text (in this case `some text` and `some foo text` is the extra symbols):

```
1000 (A) some text foo 5 10 10 10
1001 some foo text foo 5 10 10 10
1002 foo 5 10 10 10
1003 bar w225 10 10 10
```

Unsurprisingly this does not produce the desired results. Is there a prefered technique to do this correctly?

Full example here: https://regex101.com/r/bVX9zH/1

Edit: The desired behaviour is that group `a3` matches as **much** text as possible and `extra` as **little** as possible. In the example case every line does not have a `a3` match (i.e. in the first line `a3` should contain `foo 5`).

Comment: Sorry, but what are the expected results? BTW, see https://regex101.com/r/bVX9zH/2

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've included the expected results.

Comment: Swap the two groups: https://regex101.com/r/bVX9zH/3

Comment: The extra block only comes before `a3`. So swapping them will not solve the problem.

Comment: So what *can* you do with the pattern if you cannot re-write it?

Comment: The *only* thing I *can't* do, is change the ordering of subpatterns (which is a1, a2?, extra?, a3?, a4).